# Android addView() resets ImageMatrix of ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, zooming, imagebutton

I am trying to add `ImageButton`'s in my Android Application from a list `imgBtns` to an already existing `ImageView` in this way:

```
for (int k = 0; k < imgBtns.size(); k++) {
    zoomLayout.addView(imgBtns.get(k));
}
```

The `ImageView` is zoomable via an `ImageMatrix` that adjusts according to the finger gestures.

My Problem is, that when I add the `ImageButton`, the `ImageMatrix` of the `ImageView` somehow resets and I end up looking at the fully zoomed out image!
I tried assigning the matrix manually after the adding and I played with the `LayoutParams`, but it always resets the `ImageMatrix`!

Does someone have an idea why this happens and how I can add my `ImageButton`'s to the zoomed-in `ImageView` so that it stays zoomed-in?

> #### EDIT:
>
> It turns out the `ImageMatrix` doesn't get reseted, but something else instead. My guess is, that adding a View to the Layout somehow resets the Layout and its children. I don't know what exactly is going on, but I think changing the Layout after the `onCreate()` has some complicated consequences...

Comment: what is `scaleType` of  `imgBtns.get(k)` when you call `addView`?

Comment: @pskink: I've tried initializing the 'ImageButton' 's with 'ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX' and 'ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER' , but it doesn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: does it have to be an `ImageButton`? why not a custom `View` where you have the full control of what is drawn?

Comment: you're right, it doesn't have to be a `ImageButton` for my purpose. So I just tried it with a `View`, but Views don't have the `setMaxHeigth() setMaxWidth()` functions, so I think I can't set their size so easily. I then tried using a `ImageView`, but again the same problem occurs like when using `ImageButton` 's: no zooming possible anymore...

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: so far I have these `ImageButton`'s on a picture (the zoomable `ImageView`) on certain positions. Now all I want to achieve is that when I zoom into the picture, that only the still visible buttons (with their position within the zoomed-in region) are visible. <br/> 
The problem is, I have to delete all the `ImageButton`'s as soon as I touch the screen to zoom/slide, because otherwise the buttons are in the way of the gesture detection. Therefore I have to redraw them after the zooming/sliding on a new position.

Comment: cannot you simply draw the bitmaps using the matrix?